# how convert get data from database into associative array laravel 8?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-8

I have data from a database that I call in the controller and I want to convert it to an associative array

the data i call

```
$dosen = Criteria::with(['lecturer'])->get();
```

and want to convert it to an associative array like below

```
 $rating = [
        'User A' => [3, null, 5, null, null, null],
        'Matakuliah B' => [2, 3, null, 3, 4, null],
        'Matakuliah C' => [5, 4, 4, null, 5, null],
        'User D' => [5, 5, 2, null, 5, 4],
    ];
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the data you currently get which will get converted to the associative array you are sharing? Also show us what you already tried, usually it's more likely for us to work with what you have rather than make up a new solution

Comment: sample data I want to change https://ibb.co/BLvtSpr thanks

Comment: That data doesn't even remotely resemble the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a database collection to an array by using the toArray() method on your collection. Try this

```
$dosen = Criteria::with(['lecturer'])->get()->toArray();
```

Comment: not going well thanks for the answer